# Como arrumar o cursor de input text que fica no meio

Tags: css

Eu estou com um problema onde eu tenho um input text modificado e quando vou digitar ele começa la no meio, e eu quero deixa-lo na esquerda.

Tentei usar `text-align: left;` de um tópico que eu vi aqui no *stackoverflow* mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.Discord {
  width: 700px;
  height: 550px;
  position: relative;
  left: 350px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #36393f;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.Discord .Chat {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 12px 314px;
  background-color: #40444b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 505px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #40444b;
  outline: none;
  /*Tirar aquela borda azul quando clica na barra*/
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="Discord">
  <input type="text" class="Chat">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema aí é que você colocou um `padding` right/left enorme de `314px` no input:

```
padding: 12px 314px;
```

Me parece ter sido uma gambiarra apenas para que o input ficasse com a mesma largura da div onde ele está, porém isso gerou esse problema agora, onde a área de digitação ficou pequena e posicionada no meio do elemento, e o `text-align: left;` não irá resolver, porque o problema não é o alinhamento do texto.

O que você precisa fazer é consertar esse `padding`, deixando apenas o valor `12px`:

```
padding: 12px;
```

Porque aí irá aplicar `12px` de espaçamento interno em todas as direções (*top/right/bottom/left*).

Feito isso é preciso ajustar a largura do input. Para isso, você pode usar o `calc()`, subtraindo de `100%` a soma dos paddings `right` e `left`, 2 vezes o `left` de `10px` e das bordas de 1px do próprio input:

```
- paddings right/left: 24px (12px cada)
- left: 10px * 2 = 20px
- bordas right/left: 1px * 2 = 2px
- TOTAL: 46px
```

Com isso, o input deverá ter:

```
width: calc(100% - 46px);
```

Ou, como a div é fixa, você pode descontar os `46px` da largura fixa da div:

```
width: calc(700px - 46px);
```

Ou passar logo direto o resultado da subtração:

```
width: 654px;
```

**Veja:**

```css
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.Discord {
width: 700px;
height: 550px;
position: relative;
left: 350px;
top: 50px;
background-color: #36393f;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.Discord .Chat {
width: calc(700px - 46px);
height: 10px;
padding: 12px;
background-color: #40444b;
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;
top: 505px ;
left: 10px;
border: 1px solid;
border-color: #40444b;
outline: none; /*Tirar aquela borda azul quando clica na barra*/
/*text-align: left;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="Discord">
   <input type="text" class="Chat">
</div>
```